# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_execute_on_connection' SQLAlchemy in Lyft Amundsen

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating a data catalog using Lyft Amundsen. I started it with docker and now I want to connect to database in PostgreSQL and get my tables from database. I have sample_postgres_loader.py from documentation:

```
# Copyright Contributors to the Amundsen project.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

"""
This is a example script which demo how to load data
into Neo4j and Elasticsearch without using an Airflow DAG.

"""

import logging
import sys
import textwrap
import uuid

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import text
from databuilder.extractor.neo4j_extractor import Neo4jExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.neo4j_search_data_extractor import Neo4jSearchDataExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.postgres_metadata_extractor import PostgresMetadataExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.sql_alchemy_extractor import SQLAlchemyExtractor
from databuilder.job.job import DefaultJob
from databuilder.loader.file_system_elasticsearch_json_loader import FSElasticsearchJSONLoader
from databuilder.loader.file_system_neo4j_csv_loader import FsNeo4jCSVLoader
from databuilder.publisher import neo4j_csv_publisher
from databuilder.publisher.elasticsearch_publisher import ElasticsearchPublisher
from databuilder.publisher.neo4j_csv_publisher import Neo4jCsvPublisher
from databuilder.task.task import DefaultTask
from databuilder.transformer.base_transformer import NoopTransformer

es_host = None
neo_host = None
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    es_host = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    neo_host = sys.argv[2]

es = Elasticsearch([
    {'host': es_host if es_host else 'localhost'},
])

DB_FILE = '/tmp/test.db'
SQLITE_CONN_STRING = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
Base = declarative_base()

NEO4J_ENDPOINT = f'bolt://{neo_host or "localhost"}:7687'

neo4j_endpoint = NEO4J_ENDPOINT

neo4j_user = 'neo4j'
neo4j_password = 'test'

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# todo: connection string needs to change
def connection_string():
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'mypassword'
    host = 'localhost'
    port = '5432'
    db = 'mydatabase'
    return "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (user, password, host, port, db)


def run_postgres_job():
    where_clause_suffix = text(textwrap.dedent("""
        SELECT
            current_database() as cluster,
            st.schemaname as schema,
            st.relname as name,
            pgtd.description as description,
            att.attname as col_name,
            pgtyp.typname as col_type,
            pgcd.description as col_description,
            att.attnum as col_sort_order
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute att
        INNER JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
            on att.attrelid=st.relid
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_type pgtyp
            on pgtyp.oid=att.atttypid
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_description pgtd
            on pgtd.objoid=st.relid and pgtd.objsubid=0
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_description pgcd
            on pgcd.objoid=st.relid and pgcd.objsubid=att.attnum
        WHERE att.attnum >=0 and schemaname = 'public'
        ORDER by cluster, schema, name, col_sort_order
        """))

    tmp_folder = '/var/tmp/amundsen/table_metadata'
    node_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/nodes/'
    relationship_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/relationships/'

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        f'extractor.postgres_metadata.{PostgresMetadataExtractor.WHERE_CLAUSE_SUFFIX_KEY}': where_clause_suffix,
        f'extractor.postgres_metadata.{PostgresMetadataExtractor.USE_CATALOG_AS_CLUSTER_NAME}': True,
        f'extractor.postgres_metadata.extractor.sqlalchemy.{SQLAlchemyExtractor.CONN_STRING}': connection_string(),
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.NODE_DIR_PATH}': node_files_folder,
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.RELATION_DIR_PATH}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.SHOULD_DELETE_CREATED_DIR}': True,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NODE_FILES_DIR}': node_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.RELATION_FILES_DIR}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_END_POINT_KEY}': neo4j_endpoint,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_USER}': neo4j_user,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_PASSWORD}': neo4j_password,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.JOB_PUBLISH_TAG}': 'unique_tag',  # should use unique tag here like {ds}
    })
    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=DefaultTask(extractor=PostgresMetadataExtractor(), loader=FsNeo4jCSVLoader()),
                     publisher=Neo4jCsvPublisher())
    return job


def create_es_publisher_sample_job(elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
                                   elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table',
                                   model_name='databuilder.models.table_elasticsearch_document.TableESDocument',
                                   cypher_query=None,
                                   elasticsearch_mapping=None):
    """
    :param elasticsearch_index_alias:  alias for Elasticsearch used in
                                       amundsensearchlibrary/search_service/config.py as an index
    :param elasticsearch_doc_type_key: name the ElasticSearch index is prepended with. Defaults to `table` resulting in
                                       `table_search_index`
    :param model_name:                 the Databuilder model class used in transporting between Extractor and Loader
    :param cypher_query:               Query handed to the `Neo4jSearchDataExtractor` class, if None is given (default)
                                       it uses the `Table` query baked into the Extractor
    :param elasticsearch_mapping:      Elasticsearch field mapping "DDL" handed to the `ElasticsearchPublisher` class,
                                       if None is given (default) it uses the `Table` query baked into the Publisher
    """
    # loader saves data to this location and publisher reads it from here
    extracted_search_data_path = '/var/tmp/amundsen/search_data.json'

    task = DefaultTask(loader=FSElasticsearchJSONLoader(),
                       extractor=Neo4jSearchDataExtractor(),
                       transformer=NoopTransformer())

    # elastic search client instance
    elasticsearch_client = es
    # unique name of new index in Elasticsearch
    elasticsearch_new_index_key = 'tables' + str(uuid.uuid4())

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.GRAPH_URL_CONFIG_KEY}': neo4j_endpoint,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.MODEL_CLASS_CONFIG_KEY}': model_name,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.NEO4J_AUTH_USER}': neo4j_user,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.NEO4J_AUTH_PW}': neo4j_password,
        f'loader.filesystem.elasticsearch.{FSElasticsearchJSONLoader.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY}': extracted_search_data_path,
        f'loader.filesystem.elasticsearch.{FSElasticsearchJSONLoader.FILE_MODE_CONFIG_KEY}': 'w',
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY}': extracted_search_data_path,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_MODE_CONFIG_KEY}': 'r',
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_CLIENT_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_client,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_NEW_INDEX_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_new_index_key,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_DOC_TYPE_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_doc_type_key,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_ALIAS_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_index_alias,
    })

    # only optionally add these keys, so need to dynamically `put` them
    if cypher_query:
        job_config.put(f'extractor.search_data.{Neo4jSearchDataExtractor.CYPHER_QUERY_CONFIG_KEY}',
                       cypher_query)
    if elasticsearch_mapping:
        job_config.put(f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_MAPPING_CONFIG_KEY}',
                       elasticsearch_mapping)

    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=task,
                     publisher=ElasticsearchPublisher())
    return job


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Uncomment next line to get INFO level logging
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    loading_job = run_postgres_job()
    loading_job.launch()

    job_es_table = create_es_publisher_sample_job(
        elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
        elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table',
        model_name='databuilder.models.table_elasticsearch_document.TableESDocument')
    job_es_table.launch()
```

But when I type in console: python example/scripts/sample_postgres_loader.py there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1408, in execute
    meth = statement._execute_on_connection
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_execute_on_connection'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\example\scripts\sample_postgres_loader.py", line 185, in <module>
    loading_job.launch()
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\job\job.py", line 76, in launch
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\job\job.py", line 64, in launch
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\job\job.py", line 51, in _init
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\task\task.py", line 45, in init
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\extractor\base_postgres_metadata_extractor.py", line 68, in init
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\extractor\sql_alchemy_extractor.py", line 40, in init
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\amundsen_databuilder-7.4.4-py3.9.egg\databuilder\extractor\sql_alchemy_extractor.py", line 65, in _execute_query
  File "X:\amundsen\amundsen\databuilder\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1410, in execute
    raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(statement) from err
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: "\n            SELECT\n                current_database() as cluster,\n                st.schemaname as schema,\n                st.relname as name,\n                pgtd.description as description,\n                att.attname as col_name,\n                pgtyp.typname as col_type,\n                pgcd.description as col_description,\n                att.attnum as col_sort_order\n            FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute att\n            INNER JOIN\n                pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st\n                on att.attrelid=st.relid\n            LEFT JOIN\n                pg_catalog.pg_type pgtyp\n                on pgtyp.oid=att.atttypid\n            LEFT JOIN\n                pg_catalog.pg_description pgtd\n                on pgtd.objoid=st.relid and pgtd.objsubid=0\n            LEFT JOIN\n              pg_catalog.pg_description pgcd\n              on pgcd.objoid=st.relid and pgcd.objsubid=att.attnum\n            WHERE att.attnum >=0 and \nSELECT\n    current_database() as cluster,\n    st.schemaname as schema,\n    st.relname as name,\n    pgtd.description as description,\n    att.attname as col_name,\n    pgtyp.typname as col_type,\n    pgcd.description as col_description,\n    att.attnum as col_sort_order\nFROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute att\nINNER JOIN\n    pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st\n    on att.attrelid=st.relid\nLEFT JOIN\n    pg_catalog.pg_type pgtyp\n    on pgtyp.oid=att.atttypid\nLEFT JOIN\n    pg_catalog.pg_description pgtd\n    on pgtd.objoid=st.relid and pgtd.objsubid=0\nLEFT JOIN\n    pg_catalog.pg_description pgcd\n    on pgcd.objoid=st.relid and pgcd.objsubid=att.attnum\nWHERE att.attnum >=0 and schemaname = 'public'\nORDER by cluster, schema, name, col_sort_order\n\n            ORDER by cluster, schema, name, col_sort_order;\n        "
```

I already changed this:

```
where_clause_suffix = textwrap.dedent("""
        where table_schema = 'public'
    """)
```

to this:

```
    where_clause_suffix = text(textwrap.dedent("""
        SELECT
            current_database() as cluster,
            st.schemaname as schema,
            st.relname as name,
            pgtd.description as description,
            att.attname as col_name,
            pgtyp.typname as col_type,
            pgcd.description as col_description,
            att.attnum as col_sort_order
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute att
        INNER JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
            on att.attrelid=st.relid
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_type pgtyp
            on pgtyp.oid=att.atttypid
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_description pgtd
            on pgtd.objoid=st.relid and pgtd.objsubid=0
        LEFT JOIN
            pg_catalog.pg_description pgcd
            on pgcd.objoid=st.relid and pgcd.objsubid=att.attnum
        WHERE att.attnum >=0 and schemaname = 'public'
        ORDER by cluster, schema, name, col_sort_order
        """))
```

But still error is the same. Where is a problem? How to fix it?

Comment: Check if Amundsen has been updated to work with SQLAlchemy 2. You may need to downgrade to SQLAlchemy 1.4.